# How to use the :not selector in Cytoscape.js? (To select nodes that don't have an attribute)

Tags: javascript, graph, css-selectors, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to use the **:not** selector in cytoscape.js. I want to select all nodes that don't have a specific attribute to open an context menu. E.g.:

```
cy.cxtmenu({
    selector: not('node.selection'),
    commands: [ .... ]
});
```

But I'm not sure how I can do this in cytoscape.js. Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[^name]
Matches elements if the specified data attribute is not defined, i.e. undefined (e.g [^foo]). Here, null is considered a defined value.

http://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/data

Comment: Thanks. It works. In my case it is: selector: 'node[^selection]'

Answer (score 0):

Update in 2022:

In case you don't have control over the selector, but just want the opposite set, use this:

```js
// initialize Cytoscape
let cy = cytoscape()
// select all and remove the rest
cy.$("*").not(cytoscapeSelector)
```